# RemoteInput can't retrieve extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I open a RemoteInput via intent but need to pass some additional data. I eventually retrieve it in the onActivityResult

Launch:

```
    Bundle d = new Bundle();
    d.putString("chatID", id);

    RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("remote_input")
            .setLabel("Send to "+name)
            .addExtras(d)
            .build();
    RemoteInput[] remoteInputs = new RemoteInput[]{remoteInput};

    Intent intent = new Intent(RemoteInputIntent.ACTION_REMOTE_INPUT);
    intent.putExtra(RemoteInputIntent.EXTRA_REMOTE_INPUTS, remoteInputs);
    intent.putExtra("chatID", id);
    intent.putExtra("asd", "das");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Retrieve:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(data.getExtras());

    System.out.println(data);

    System.out.println(data.getExtras().toString());
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        System.out.println(data);
        Bundle results = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(data);
        String text = results.getCharSequence("remote_input").toString();

        System.out.println("  >");
        Bundle c = data.getExtras();
        //Object cd = data.getExtras().get("remote_input_types");
        Object cd = results.get("remote_input");
        System.out.println(cd);
        System.out.println(cd.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(c.keySet());
        System.out.println("  <");

        Set<String> keys = c.keySet();

        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
```

None of what I try brings up "chatID", it simply seems to be missing from the keys. How else am I supposed to get the extras?

Comment: have a same issue. how you solved it?

Comment: Please check the reply. I honestly have no idea if it helped me back then but looking at some old code I did `private Bundle[] myDataTransfer = { null };` then in the launch `Bundle myData = new Bundle();
        myData.putString("chatID", id);
        myDataTransfer[0] = myData;` and then `Bundle myData = myDataTransfer[0];
            String onlineid = myData.getString("chatID");
            System.out.println(onlineid);`. Sorry for the bad formatting but this really isn't what you should to but it did work for me back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you are sending or *launching* the data.
Try using putExtra**S**() instead of putExtra(). PutExtras() is used to hold object of bundle class.

Launch:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Key, value);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, className);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
intent.setFlags(intFlag);
startActivityForResult();
```

Retrieve:

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
           Bundle dataBundle = data.getExtras();
           //Use data bundle
        }
   }
```